# Is it correct to avoid mentioning any additional events with the past continuous?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

Is it correct to say "That evening I was doing chemistry for 90 minutes." without adding any actions occured during that period (while someone was doing something or did something - these things) or event that interrupted my action?

Comment: Do you mean 'doing chemical experiments' or 'studying chemistry'? Yes, you might say that if you were asked how you spent the evening.

Comment: As @KateBunting said, if someone asked you *What were you doing on Monday night?* replying with the past continuous would be perfectly natural. But it would be a bit odd to reply using the continuous if he'd asked *What did you do on Monday night?* And it would be *really* odd to start a conversation with *I was doing chemistry for 90 minutes last night* if your *next* utterance wasn't about ***something else that happened then.*** But obviously you're not thinking about *starting* a conversation, since ***that*** in your example indicates that the relevant day has already been mentioned.

Comment: @KateBunting I meant  'studying chemistry'